# compute connectedcomponents using spark and graphframes on a very large number of vertices

Tags: apache-spark, graphframes

I am working with a very large graph of approximately 100 million vertices and I am using graphframes.connectedcomponents with spark to resolve the graph. The output of the solution is a forest like graph. I tried running by bumping up the driver memory but the job timed out after 100 mins.

What is an efficient way of working with large number of vertices?